# Launch Location Settings intent from preferences XML file

Tags: android, android-intent, android-preferences

I want to launch System's Location Settings from an `Intent`. I know that programmatically it goes like this

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

but I need to do it from the XML of a `Preference`. I try like this

```
<Preference
    android:title="@string/pref_title" >
    <intent android:action="android.settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS" />
</Preference>
```

but it does not work, I always get an `ActivityNotFoundException`. How can I launch that System Location Settings from an XML Intent?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can create a: `PreferenceActivity` that will represent you preferences and then you can assign an `onClick` to your preference like this:

```
Preference goToLocationSettings = (Preference) findPreference("goToLocationSettings");
goToLocationSettings.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(viewIntent);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

And you will need to assign a key to your preference in the xml file:

```
<Preference
    android:key="goToLocationSettings"
    android:title="@string/pref_title" />
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but does it mean there is no way to invoke that action from XML then?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way and I think there isn't one.

Comment: I'm getting an `AndroidRuntimeException`: "Calling `StartActivity()` from outside of an activity". I guess this is because of the context of `onPreferenceClick()`...

Comment: you can do something like this: YourActivityName.this as the context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="key_location"
    android:summary="location settings"
    android:title="Open location settings">

    <intent android:action="android.settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```