# DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS crashes app in gingerbread

Tags: android

The following code works perfectly in jelly bean buts crashes in Gingerbread

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS);
startActivity(i);
```

in Gingerbread is causes error

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS }
```

is there any way to go to development setting in gingerbread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this exception because as there is no Activity which can handle

```
  Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS
```

Intent action in Gingerbread. and when you are starting any Activity with Intent actions, don't forget to validate whether is there any Activity which can handle your Intent action.

see example...

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS);
    ComponentName componentName = intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager());
    if (componentName == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Activity to handle Intent action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: There is a development settings page in android setting in gingerbread . how can i go to that page if settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS is not the right action

Comment: I didn't see Developer Settings option in Settings in Gingerbread. did you seen?

Comment: yes. its in settings > application > developer . so the action is different in Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(i);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, still the same issue

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001521/launch-location-settings-intent-from-preferences-xml-file

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using getApplicationContext() instead of mContext.

or use

```
Intent i =   new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS);
```

startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```