# Open application settings via Intent from preferences.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, preferences

I would like to open the application settings by clicking on a preferences entry. So I added an intent to the preferences.xml

```
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="DELETE_DATA"
        android:title="@string/pref_delete_data">
        <intent android:action="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

and I've added an Intent-filter to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
...
```

With the code above, there is no action or error. But I don't know why...
If I'm removing the `<category>` there comes an error, so the intent is fired. Any ideas?

Device: HTC One M8 with Android 4.4.4

Comment: you must have a button or something in the preferences screen to get to you to the application settings correct??

Comment: Well the `PreferenceScreen` is an embedded element (so this is the button). It works if I fire the intent by code via OnPreferenceClickListener. But I would prefer to do this via `preferences.xml`. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For others interested in how OP used the OnPreferenceClickListener, [check out this answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001521/launch-location-settings-intent-from-preferences-xml-file). But to launch an activity directly from an intent, this worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/pref_title_category_name">
  <PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/pref_title_activity_name"
    android:key="pref_launch_settings">
  <intent
    android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:data="<data>"
    android:targetPackage="<package name>"
    android:targetClass="<target class>" />
  </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

**data** = Full package name plus activity name. I.e., com.example.myapp.ActivityName

**package name** = Package name as defined in the root of your manifest file. I.e., com.example.myapp

**targetClass** = full package path again, i.e., com.example.myapp.ActivityName

Note that I'm using the `<intent>` tag this way inside of a `PreferenceScreen`, rather than a `PreferenceCategory`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This worked. Wonder why it wasn't voted. I haven't found a better answer yet.

Comment: I'd like to point out if you're using product flavours, "package name" should be the application Id.

Comment: is it possible to finish the calling activity using this xml declaration?

Answer (score 4):

Set android:data to your package name. Replace **com.myapp** (below) with the name of your app's package name found in the manifest file.

```
  <PreferenceScreen
        android:title="@string/system_settings_preference_title" >
        <intent android:action="android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS"
            android:data="package:com.myapp"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        <Preference android:title="@string/pref_app_version"
        android:summary="@string/pref_app_version_summary">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="YOUR APPLICATION ID"
            android:targetClass="com.my.java.packagename.MyActivity"/>
    </Preference>
```

Just something I noticed today. If you're working with different product flavours, make sure **targetpackage** is your **applicationId** as defined in build.gradle.

Comment: It is possible to generate a per-flavor string property for the applicationId automatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55300377/539443