# Using PreferenceScreen with applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, preferenceactivity

I'm having some problems making `PreferenceScreen` and `applicationIdSuffix` work together.

Supposing my app package/`applicationId` is `com.myapp` in Gradle and in AndroidManifest.xml, and `applicationIdSuffix` is defined as:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
    }
}
```

If I define a `PreferenceScreen` as the following

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="key_about" android:summary="something" android:title="About">
    <intent
        android:targetClass="com.myapp.activities.AboutActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.myapp" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

when launching the debug version of the app I get an exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { (...) } from ProcessRecord{(...)} (pid=13658, uid=10105) not exported from uid 10067
```

which makes sense, as I'm trying to launch an activity from a different application. The problem is that I can't find a way to Android launch the right activity.

If I change `targetClass` to ".activities.AboutActivity" it still can't find the activity

```
ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myapp.dev/.activities.AboutActivity}
```

I even tried to define a value for each of the versions with the correct package:

```
android:targetClass="@string/classname"
android:targetPackage="@string/packagename"
```

but it can't find the right activity:

```
ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
    {com.myapp.dev/com.myapp.dev.activities.AboutActivity};
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

So how can I make this work?

Comment: According to the exception here, I think it says that you should define your AboutActivity in the manifest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your confusion comes from the fact that `applicationIdSuffix` only changes the package name of the application (its unique id), but does not change the java package name of your classes inside the application, including your Activity.

This means that you should declare in your preferences:

```
android:targetClass="com.myapp.activities.AboutActivity"
android:targetPackage="@string/packagename"
```

Where `targetClass` is always the same, while `targetPackage` depends on your build type and can be `com.myapp` or `com.myapp.dev`.

Comment: won't this still fail, given that the applicationId won't have the suffix?

Comment: You should define the string constant in 2 different folders matching the declared build types and give the string the same value as the application Id (with and without suffix). Unfortunately it's not possible yet to use applicationId as a variable in resources, you can only do it in the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no direct way to include the effective `applicationId` into other XML files than the AndroidManifest (where it is available as `${applicationId}`), so you need to create a string property for it.

Because the gradle `applicationId` value changes based on the flavor, you can not use it directly to define the string property. Instead, you need to create an `afterEvaluate` rule in `build.gradle` to generate it for all variants:

```
afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue 'string', 'application_id', variant.applicationId
    }
}
```

This will create a `@string/application_id` (or `R.string.application_id`) that you can use wherever needed, e.g. in your layout / preferences XML (the class name doesn't need to be changed because it is based on the java package that's the same for all flavors):

```xml
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="key_about" android:summary="something" android:title="About">
    <intent
        android:targetClass="com.myapp.activities.AboutActivity"
        android:targetPackage="@string/application_id" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This solution is based on https://gist.github.com/Takhion/74b67cb518e90faf2708 which also provides a provider property.

Comment: Thank you!
`afterEvaluate` should be under `productFlavors` (itself under `android`)

Answer (score 0):

What I do in my app is attach an `onPreferenceClickListener` to the preference in its host activity, and build the intent inside that listener's `onPreferenceClick` method. By generating the intent from code, you directly reference the target class and the question of packages never comes up.