# Android: deep linking into specific preference screen on back button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-preferences, android-deep-link

I have read the following posts

1. [Open application settings via Intent from preferences.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154832/open-application-settings-via-intent-from-preferences-xml)
2. [Using PreferenceScreen with applicationIdSuffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114385/using-preferencescreen-with-applicationidsuffix/55300377#55300377)

But I have not been able to figure out how to deep link so that a specific screen is loaded. This is my use case. I have set up a deep link activity handler with intent filters to deep link into a specific activity as follows. For the following deep link

> adb -e shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "myapp://link?nav=user.settings.push\&preference=notifications"

I have my activity to handle the incoming deep link as follows.

```
Uri ur = getIntent().getData();
String preference = uri.getQueryParameter("preference");
Intent processorIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
processorIntent.putExtra("preference", preference);
. . . . other attributes are added as such ONE_SHOT_FLAG etc.
startActivity(processorIntent);
```

In my SettingsActivity, I have the following

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager != null)
    {

        String settingsPreference =
            getIntent().getStringExtra("preference");
              final Fragment fragment
            if (preference != null) {
              fragment =  new NotificationPreferencesFragment();
            } else {
              fragment = new RootPreferences();
            }
            fragment.setArguments(savedInstanceState);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.master_container, fragment, "root_fragment")
                .commit();
     }
   }
 }
```

RootPreferenceFragment

This is where I define my preferences

```
    public class RootPreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat 
    {
                @Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey)
{
  final Activity activity = getActivity();

  // Initialize view models
  final ViewModelProvider viewModelProvider = ViewModelProviders.of(activity, viewModelProviderFactory);
  RootViewModel rootViewModel = viewModelProvider.get(RootViewModel.class);


   . . . . Initialise Other Preferences . . . . 

  // Notifications
  final Preference notificationsPreference = preferencesFactory.create(
    accountCategory,
    Preference.class,
    RootViewModel.ACCOUNT_NOTIFICATIONS_PREFERENCE_KEY,
    R.string.PushNotifications,
    RootViewModel.ACCOUNT_CATEGORY_KEY);
  notificationsPreference.setFragment(NotificationPreferencesFragment.class.getName());
  // I want to deep link into this one.


}
    }
```

This is how my screen looks. I am able to get into the Notifications screen but I can't come to this screen on back button. This screen is managed by RootPreferencesFragment.

How can I do it?

[image: Settings screen]